Past tenses with to be
I  wanted to ask because if I say

"When they took me to hospital she was taking care of kids."

This sentence shows that while she was taking care of the children, they took me to the hospital.  She started supervising kids before I was taken.
However, it is different with the verb "to be".

"When I was sick she was taking care of kids."

During the illness, not before, and it only works with "to be" because, for example, the sentence "When we went to be the beach we were swimming everyday" is completely nonsense.  Correct?

Note, you don't need "to be"; you can say "... she took care of the kids." Also, not related to your question, but: Note, British usage says "go to hospital," with no article, while American adds "the," or maybe "a." Also the article is needed in "take care of the kids" if you mean specific kids, probably related to you or "her"; leaving it out might just mean that she worked in a child-care capacity for kids in general.

Is there a typo in the last example? Do you mean When we went to the beach… or did you mean the past tense of the verb "to be" in When we were at the beach … It is ungrammatical to write When we went to be the beach …"


'When' is used to refer to an event that occurred at a fixed time. If referring to two events it means they either occurred together.
'While' is used to refer to a period of time during which two things happened simultaneously.

Being taken to hospital could be an event, if you mean the moment they took you away from your home. It could also be referred to as a period of time if you are referring to the journey from your home to the hospital. Assuming it is the former, your first sentence is correct.
With your second sentence, it sounds like you're probably referring to a period of sickness. A native speaker would probably say "while I was sick, she took care of the kids". However, you can also refer to a past period as an event, so it wouldn't be wrong to say "when I was sick, she took care of the kids". It seems odd to use "...she was taking care of the kids" in either of these examples because it makes it sound like your sickness coincided with her looking after the children rather than her doing it in response to your sickness.
